# GOJS, how do you bind data to the group property?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a GOJS application up and running and i'm trying to bind a parameter in my data to the group property.

If I manually set the group property in the data then it works exactly as I would expect and the nodes appear as part of the group, but if the group is set using binding then no group connection seems to be made.

What am I missing?

example showing the group being set within the data

```
var nodes = []
var nodeObj ={
    key:"groupObject",
    text:"group",
    isGroup:true
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)

  nodeObj = {
    key:"node1",
    text:"node1",
    group:"groupObject"
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)

  nodeObj = {
    key:"node2",
    text:"node2",
    group:"groupObject"
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)
}

const initDiagram = () => {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    const diagram =
      $(go.Diagram,
        {
          'undoManager.isEnabled': true,
          'clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData': { text: 'new node', color: 'lightblue' },
          model: $(go.GraphLinksModel,
            {
              linkKeyProperty: 'key' 
            })
      });

    diagram.nodeTemplate = 
        $(go.Node, 'Auto',
            $(go.Shape, 'RoundedRectangle',
            { name: 'SHAPE', fill: 'white', strokeWidth: 0 },
            new go.Binding('fill', 'color')),
            $(go.TextBlock,
            { margin: 8, editable: true, stroke:"black" },
            new go.Binding('text').makeTwoWay()
            )
        );

    diagram.groupTemplate = 
      $(go.Group, "Vertical", $(go.GridLayout,{wrappingColumn:1}),
        $(go.TextBlock,         // group title
          { alignment: go.Spot.Center, font: "Bold 15pt Sans-Serif" },
          new go.Binding("text")),  
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",  // surrounds the Placeholder
            {fill: "lightblue" }),
          $(go.Placeholder,
            { padding: 5}),
        )
    );
    return diagram;
  }
```

This works ^^^

Now if I set the group parameter in the data to "groupName" instead of group, then bind group to groupName in the init function, the nodes no longer appear as part of the group

```
var nodes = []
var nodeObj ={
    key:"groupObject",
    text:"group",
    isGroup:true
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)

  nodeObj = {
    key:"node1",
    text:"node1",
    groupName:"groupObject"      //this line has changed
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)

  nodeObj = {
    key:"node2",
    text:"node2",
    groupName:"groupObject"      //This line has changed
  }
  nodes.push(nodeObj)
}

const initDiagram = () => {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    const diagram =
      $(go.Diagram,
        {
          'undoManager.isEnabled': true,
          'clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData': { text: 'new node', color: 'lightblue' },
          model: $(go.GraphLinksModel,
            {
              linkKeyProperty: 'key'
            })
      });

    diagram.nodeTemplate = 
        $(go.Node, 'Auto',
            new go.Binding('group','groupName'),      //this line has changed
            $(go.Shape, 'RoundedRectangle',
            { name: 'SHAPE', fill: 'white', strokeWidth: 0 },
            new go.Binding('fill', 'color')),
            $(go.TextBlock,
            { margin: 8, editable: true, stroke:"black" },
            new go.Binding('text').makeTwoWay()
            )
        );

    diagram.groupTemplate = 
      $(go.Group, "Vertical", $(go.GridLayout,{wrappingColumn:1}),
        $(go.TextBlock,         // group title
          { alignment: go.Spot.Center, font: "Bold 15pt Sans-Serif" },
          new go.Binding("text")),  
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
            {fill: "lightblue" }),
          $(go.Placeholder,
            { padding: 5}),
        )
    );
    return diagram;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are used to keep the properties of the GraphObjects of one Part up-to-date with properties on that Part's model data.  Bindings are not used for maintaining relationships between Parts.  Only models know how to interpret and maintain relationships.

If you want to use the data property "groupName" instead of "group" to refer to the node's containing group, set **GraphLinksModel.nodeGroupKeyProperty** to "groupName".  Preferably before you set **Model.nodeDataArray**.

Also, please read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html#ChangingGraphStructure.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have misunderstood the binding concept.